# Set MIN\MAX height of elevation map (PNG) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, elevation

How exactly can I
set MIN \ MAX height (in meters like [0, 1500]) for my height map (PNG) in QGIS

Answer (score 2):

Right Click your layer in the Layers window.  Select Layer Properties and then select Symbology.  Expand the Min/Max Value settings and click User_defined.  Set the values to your choice.

[image]

Comment: Changes in the MIN\MAX in symbology do not affect the height, the occupation of the heights is still not correct

Comment: i try to create color relief map by gdaldem color-relief, but i dont see options to set right range

Comment: Ah, set them in the color text file.  See these examples: https://blog.mastermaps.com/2012/06/creating-color-relief-and-slope-shading.html

Comment: @Oleg Pershun, edit your question to include those important new details.

Comment: I solved my problem by converting raster with `gdal_translate -scale 0 64840 0 1500`